# Understanding companion object in scala

Tags: scala, oop

While learning Scala, I came across interesting concept  of companion object. Companion object can used to  define static methods in Scala. Need few clarifications in the below Spark Scala code in regard of companion object.

```
 class BballStatCounter extends Serializable {
  val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
  var missing: Long = 0

  def add(x: Double): BballStatCounter = {
    if (x.isNaN) {
      missing += 1
    } else {
      stats.merge(x)
    }
    this
  }
}
object BballStatCounter extends Serializable {
  def apply(x: Double) = new BballStatCounter().add(x)
}
```

Above code is invoked using `val stat3 = stats1.map(b=>BballStatCounter(b))`.

1. What is  nature of  variables `stats` and `missing` declared in the
   class? Is it similar to class attributes of Python?
2. What  is the significance of `apply` method in here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [so]. If you have two questions, please ask two questions, not put two questions into one question. Your two questions are not related to each other, so it is hard to answer them in one answer. Plus, at least one of your questions has already been asked and answered multiple times already on [so], but it is impossible to point this question to the duplicate because of the other question that is intermingled with it. Also, in the title of your question, you ask about companion objects, but neither of your two questions has to do with companion objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `stats and missing` are class attributes and each instance of BballStatCounter will have their own copy of them just like in Python.

In Scala the method `apply` serves a special purpose, if any object has a method apply and if that object is used as function calling notation like Obj() then the compiler replaces that with its apply method calling, like Obj.apply() .

The apply method is generally used as a constructor in a Class Companion object.
All the collection Classes in Scala has a Companion Object with apply method, thus you are able to create a list like : List(1,2,3,4)

Thus  in your above code BballStatCounter(b) will get compiled to BballStatCounter.apply(b)

Answer (score 0):

1. `stats` and `missing` are members of the class `BcStatCounter`. `stats` is a `val` so it cannot be changed once it has been defined. `missing` is a `var` so it is more like a traditional variable and can be updated, as it is in the `add` method. Every instance of `BcStatCounter` will have these members. (Unlike Python, you can't add or remove members from a Scala object)
2. The `apply` method is a shortcut that makes objects look like functions. If you have an object `x` with an `apply` method, you write `x(...)` and the compiler will automatically convert this to `x.apply(...)`. In this case it means that you can call `BballStatCounter(1.0)` and this will call the `apply` method on the `BballStatCounter` object.

Neither of these questions is really about companion objects, this is just the normal Scala class framework.

Please note the remarks in the comments about asking multiple questions.